# Choosing my ending in GTA 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have a lot of different autosaves...

> ...and it autosaved right after I chose to  kill Trevor.

I want to know if I can access my other autosaves so I can retry it. I have already tried going back to a older save and it hasn't worked. Any ideas?

Comment: There should only be 1 autosave, which is shared among all of your games/saves. The game warns you about this, when you try to start a new game.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you picked the ending that you wanted, you can replay the other two options.

Navigate the start menu to the replay option, scroll to the bottom, and you should see the following 3 missions:

1. Something Sensible (Option A)
2. The Time's Come (Option B)
3. The Third Way (Option C)

**Note**: The stuff in the parentheses won't be there, I added that.

If you wanted to change the outcome of your end game, you would need to load another save sometime before the final mission.  If you don't have one, then you'll have to start a new game to change the end out come.